# gef rectangle figure single click

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-gef, draw2d

I am doing a small project in Draw2d and GEF. I need to get the single click through performRequest() method. Currently I am getting double clicking through performRequest().
There I am checking request.getType()== open then it is double click. But for single click how do I check? Is it possible without mouse listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single click is `RequestConstants.REQ_SELECTION`. 
Double click is `RequestConstants.REQ_OPEN`.

Comment: Right... fixing the answer